# Delete Item GridView Windows 8 Metro

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I an trying to delete items from a GridView control. When I click delete, the GridView fails to update

I have bound a GridView with a list of orders in an observable collection. Here is my order class:

```
public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Order() { }
    private int _id;
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {

            this._id = value;
            Notify("ID");
        }
    }
    public int RestaurantID { get; set;}
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    [Ignore]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [Ignore]
    protected void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is my data binding code:

```
 ObservableCollection<Order> orderCollection = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
            foreach (Order ord in orders)
            {
                orderCollection.Add(ord);
            }

            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = orderCollection;
```

My delete button exists in the GridView's DataTemplate. Here is my delete code:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnDelete = (Button)sender;
        Order order = btnDelete.DataContext as Order;
        repository.DeleteOrder(order.Id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code is only removing the item from the repository.  You also need to remove it from the `ObservableCollection`.  Try adding this under `repository.DeleteOrder(order.Id)`:

```
orderCollection.Remove(order);
```